# Entity Framework doesn't apply changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with EF almost a year, and suddenly It stopped to update database regarding the updated entities.
I suspect that it happened because of changing the EF version to the newer one (6.1), but, then I rolled back, nothing came better.

here is the code sample there i stacked with troubles:

```
using(ContextClass db = new ContextClass())
{
    var order = db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RecNo == 584667);
    order.primaryStatus = "Closed";
    order.secondaryStatus = "Closed";
    db.Orders.Attach(order);
    db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then running this block of code, from log I can see the following picture:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Orders]
SET [ID] = @0, [OrderNo] = @1, [ProdLine] = @2, [ProdPos] = @3, 
(and here comes every single field EXCEPT those, which I'm trying to modify!)
WHERE ([RecNo] = @20)
SELECT [RecTime], [RecStatus], [OrderStatus], [MPAStatus]
FROM [dbo].[Orders]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [RecNo] = @20
-- @0: 'Module-1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @1: 'L1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @2: 'Line2' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @3: 'Pos3' (Type = String, Size = 50)
--
-- @20: '584667' (Type = Int64)
```

And the same issue applied for every single place in my project where i just trying to update the database , not matter which methodology i'm trying to use.
entire entity, by property , doesn't matter...

Could you give me any ideas about the root of my problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code of the `Order` class? Maybe `primaryStatus` and `secondaryStatus` are missing the `public` modifier, or they are fields, not properties, ...

Comment: Also, why do you call Attach and set State explicitly?

Comment: Please also show your mapping code if you are using fluent mappings, or include your model annotations if using attributes when you post your model code. Like @marsze said, you do not need to execute another attach or set the state if the entity object is already attached to the context which it is because you just retrieved it.

Comment: Yes, you right guys. Thank you. Didn't know that then after we retrieving the entity it could be freely changed without those additional executions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omg,
just after i posted this question i found the answer which was quite obvious.
For some reason I didn't noticed as i assigned StoreGeneratedPattern property in the model to "computed". 
By doing this, i expected that i just suppress the requirement to fill this field every time as far as it is not allowed nulls and got a default value on the database side, but i didn't excepted that in that case i will not be able to change it manually  after.
I'll keep my question. Probably it could solve somebodies question quicker.